# When I first open in Centos7 kettle7.1 repository, the repository shows a blank page

Tags: etl, kettle

When I first open in Centos7 kettle7.1 repository, the repository shows a blank page。
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOXvS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below links,

```
https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-15786
https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/223175-PDI-Spoon-Blank-quot-New-Repository-Connection-quot-window/
https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/224748-Spoon-New-Repository-Connection-dialog-box-is-always-blank/
https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/219905-Connect-Repository-Button-is-not-visble-in-my-Pentaho-Community-Edition/
https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/219296-PDI-7-0-missing-connect-button/
```

Do some R&D before posting question.